# Can't update Parse Object

Tags: parse-platform, updating

I've created an object previously that I'm now trying to update in an "edit" screen

The id of the object is correct (as it correctly queries earlier in the activity to update the text labels. This should save when a button is clicked.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Product");
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    String queryString = i.getStringExtra("id");
                    query.getInBackground(queryString, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        public void done(ParseObject editProduct, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                editProduct.put("productName", ProductName.getText().toString());
                                editProduct.put("ISDN", ISDN_text.getText().toString());
                                editProduct.put("expiry", expiry_date.getText().toString());
                                editProduct.put("type", spinnercategory.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                editProduct.put("quantity", quantity.getText().toString());
                                editProduct.put("username", "Admin");
                                editProduct.put("shoppingList", true);
                                editProduct.put("mainList", false);
                                editProduct.saveInBackground();
                          }
                        }
                    });
```

This is lifted from the Parse Android developers guide, but doesn't appear to be working. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Sort of.

`editProduct.put("expiry", expiry_date.getText().toString());` is the line that's breaking it. I'm trying to pass a string to what is defined as a date at the backend, which apparently cancels the whole save operation.

Commented this out in my solution for now until I can fix the issue with the date